# create marker on click then have it be draggable

Tags: google-maps-api-3, drag, marker

I have a listener that creates an new marker when the map is clicked.  After a marker has been created, I would like to be able to drag it to a new position, if desired.  I tried using the "draggable: true" property, which works to allow dragging.  However, when the dragging ends, a new, unwanted marker is created.  How do I prevent that?  Thanks.

UPDATE:  I'm using Google Maps API V3, calling the JS routines from Delphi.  Sorry for not including that information.

Comment: This question is currently too vague to be answered... What language are you using? How is the map created? Make sure to edit your post with the code you are using and also edit your tags to reflect the language(s).

Answer (score 0):

From what little information you've given it sounds like your using Google Maps javascript API. Assuming your listener was added to a map object it shouldn't be creating additional markers when you drag the marker.

I would check to make sure you haven't added the same click listener to the marker being created. If you want something to happen when a marker is clicked it should have a separate listener for that.

This is just a guess. If you updated your answer with more details it would be easier to figure out what's going on.